# spring webflux: how to publish event from sync call for async processing?

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

i have a method that is being invoked synchronously. from this method i want to publish another event that will be processed asynchronously. eg:

sync method M is being called with parameter, this parameter needs to be sent to other server X.  M should return ASAP but X can be down. if X is down, the async processing should retry a few times a few seconds later

so i have the code that processes the single evenr / parameter:

```
 return webClient
                .post()
                .uri(...)
                .syncBody(...)
                .retrieve().bodyToMono(...)
                .retryWhen {...}
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
```

but how can i publish new event / parameter from sync call?

Comment: Can you add some more code? The one that you've posted here does not clear your intent.

Answer (score 0):

One great solution out of the box provided by spring is called as [Spring Cloud Gateway](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-gateway/2.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/) which exactly provides what you were asking for:

Its a no code app which you can start in no time and configure all your routes with yaml config and can apply the needed retry backoff etc for each route easily all by config:

**It provides a inbuilt Retry GatewayFilter Factory which does the needed solution.**

```
The Retry GatewayFilter factory supports the following parameters:

retries: The number of retries that should be attempted.

statuses: The HTTP status codes that should be retried, represented by using org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.

methods: The HTTP methods that should be retried, represented by using org.springframework.http.HttpMethod.

series: The series of status codes to be retried, represented by using org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.Series.

exceptions: A list of thrown exceptions that should be retried.

backoff: The configured exponential backoff for the retries. Retries are performed after a backoff interval of firstBackoff * (factor ^ n), where n is the iteration. If maxBackoff is configured, the maximum backoff applied is limited to maxBackoff. If basedOnPreviousValue is true, the backoff is calculated byusing prevBackoff * factor.

The following defaults are configured for Retry filter, if enabled:

retries: Three times

series: 5XX series

methods: GET method

exceptions: IOException and TimeoutException

backoff: disabled
```

Example Yaml Config again no code needed :) :

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: retry_test
        uri: http://localhost:8080/flakey
        predicates:
        - Host=*.retry.com
        filters:
        - name: Retry
          args:
            retries: 3
            statuses: BAD_GATEWAY
            methods: GET,POST
            backoff:
              firstBackoff: 10ms
              maxBackoff: 50ms
              factor: 2
              basedOnPreviousValue: false
```